# How to integrate phpexcel to silex framework?

Tags: php, phpexcel, silex

I put phpexcel to /silex/vendor/

index.php:

```
 <?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\PHPExel());
$app->get('/hello', function() {
    $objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel::newInstance();
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('123.xls');
    return 'Hello!';
});

$app->run();
```

`Fatal error: Class 'Silex\Provider\PHPExel' not found`

Comment: problem is in the `$app->register(new Silex\Provider\PHPExel());`. included PHPExel instead of PHPExcel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can install PHPexcel via composer, see https://github.com/ddeboer/phpexcel. 
To use PHPExcel via composer simply create a new instance in your code:

```
$phpExcel = new \PHPExcel();
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a Silex Service Provider for integrating PHPExcel with Silex: https://github.com/Jaza/ExcelServiceProvider

Should be dead simple to start using PHPExcel within Silex, using this package.

Answer (score 1):

First, register your own namespace:

```
$app['autoloader']->registerNamespace('MyNamespace', __DIR__.'../lib' );
```

*(Put PHPExcel file in the folder "lib" in my example)*

2 - Add the namespace at the beginning of PHPExcel file:

```
   namespace MyNamespace;
```

*(If PHPExcel is in a subfolder, don't forget to add it in the namespace path !)*

3 - Use this namespace in your main file:

```
use MyNamespace\PHPExcel as PHPExcel;
```

The main file code:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use MyNamespace\PHPExcel as PHPExcel;

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['autoloader']->registerNamespace('MyNamespace', __DIR__.'../lib' );
$app->register(new PHPExcel());
```

Comment: FYI the symfony autoloader is now deprecated and the composer autoloader is recommended instead.